# php html_entity_decode how to use

Tags: php, html-encode

I am trying to convert HTML entities from a source string to their literal character equivalent.

For example:

```
   <?php

    $string = "Hello &#8211; World";
    $converted = html_entity_decode($string);

    ?>
```

Whilst this rightly converts the entity on screen, when I look at the HTML code it is still showing the explicit entity. I need to change that so that it literally converts the entity as I am not using the string within an HTML page.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

FYI I am sending the converted string to Apple's Push notification service:

```
 $payload['aps'] = array('alert' => $converted, 'badge' => 1, 'sound' => 'default');
    $payload = json_encode($payload);
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you get the results from, e.g. where does the entitiy still get displayed? Did you `error_log` it after conversion?

Maybe you need to add the other two params to `html_entity_decode`, as `json_encode` requires the string to be UTF-8 encoded. Try this:

```
$converted=html_entity_decode($string,ENT_COMPAT,"UTF-8");
```

**Edit** Yeah, checked it in my phpsh, you're definitely required to add the two params (especially UTF-8).

Answer (score 0):

To decode an entity into a character, `html_entity_decode` needs to know what encoding you'd like your character to be in. "ü" can be represented in Latin-1, UTF-8, UTF-16 and a host of other encodings. The default is Latin-1. `&#8211;` (–, EN DASH) cannot be represented in Latin-1. Hence it stays unchanged. Tell `html_entity_decode` to decode it into an encoding that can represent that character, like UTF-8:

```
html_entity_decode($str, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')
```